# is there a way to have two active spells in fable 2 like in fable 3

Tags: fable-2

I've looked all over the internet and i loved the combination of vortex and blades in fable 3 can i do this in fable 2? If so how? I haven't tried anything yet I honestly have no idea what could possible work

Answer (score 2):

No. The combination magic you refer too was actually, in part, a new mechanic to Fable 3.

As such, the same function can not be replicated in Fable 2.